# Incorrect output in Java program

Tags: java

This is the description of the problem and here is the code that I got:

PP 10.1 Design and implement a program that reads a series of 10 inte- gers from
the user and prints their average. Read each input value as a string, and then
attempt to convert it to an integer using the Integer.parseInt method. If this process
throws a NumberFormatException (meaning that the input is not a valid number),
print an appropriate error message and prompt for the number again. Continue
reading values until 10 valid integers have been entered.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class average 
{
private int number_values;
private int[] int_values;
private double average;

public average(int number_values)
    {
    this.number_values = number_values;
    }
public void values()
    {
    String value_string = null;
    int int_value = 0,a;
    Scanner number = null;
    a = 0;
    int_values = new int [number_values];

while (a < number_values)
    {
    try{
        number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a value:");

        value_string = number.nextLine();

        int_value = Integer.parseInt(value_string);

        int_values[a++] = int_value;
        } 
    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
            {
            System.out.print("This is an invalid input. Please renter another number:");
            continue;
            }
    }
}
public void printValues()
{
System.out.println("The values are:");

    for (int a = 0; a < number_values; a++)
    {
        System.out.println("Number - " + (a + 1) + " = " + int_values);

    }
}
public double get_average()
{
int sum = 0;

for(int a = 0; a < number_values; a++)
    {
    sum += int_values[a];
    }
average = (double) sum / number_values;
return (average);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    average a = new average(10);
    a.values();
    a.printValues();
    System.out.println("Average = " + a.get_average());

}
}
```

When I enter an incorrect character it says "This is an invalid input. Please renter another number:Please enter a value:"

And when I displays the average it says Number - 1 = [I@330bedb4" for all of the values.

So the println string when I enter a incorrect input is messed up and the values are messed up. What am I missing?

Comment: please post the real code and answer (as text), not using images (didn't dv btw).

Answer (score 0):

Try `intValues[i]`, if you want to output a specific item of your array. Otherwise you get the `toString` representation of the array object itself.

And please next time post your code instread of screenshots ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing the elements of the `array`. You're printing the `array` string representation directly. The error is done in your `printValues()` method.

To solve this, you must call an element of the array. In this case, you want to call all elements, so you must use a `loop`. Here:

```
public void printValues()
{
System.out.println("The values are:");

    for (int a = 0; a < number_values; a++)
    {
        System.out.println("Number - " + (a + 1) + " = " + int_values[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you be able to help with one more thing? when I enter an invalid character it prints "This is an invalid input. Please renter another number: Please enter a value:" It's not supposed to print the "Please enter a value" part. (As you can tell I am new to Java and have spent hours looking over these two things to see what I did wrong). Thanks again for your help

Comment: @PythonWorld that's because when the exception comes in and you tell the program to `continue` the `while` loop starts again, and the "Please enter a value" line is written again on the console before asking for a number. You must introduce a new `while` loop into the exception and a `nextline()`, so the program will keep repeating this loop until the user doesn't introduce an `Integer` type.